# nginx-ingress-controller not considering the upstream service in EKS

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am trying to setup an ingress-controller to a EKS cluster. I followed the nginx guide to deploy the nginx controller.

https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installation-with-manifests/

But the nginx ingress configuration file is not considering the "service ips" in the "upstream".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXvnh.png)

Any help!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

After 2 days of debugging, I found the issue.

The "nginx-ingress" is unable to identify the "upstream service". Because the endpoint service is unable to locate the "App" due to "app" label was wrong.

It looks a silly manual mistake, but the debugging is not straight forward.

If anyone has similar issue, please try to debug with reference of below points:-

- execute the "nginx-ingress" with logs enabled (v3)
- Find the list of endpoints in the cluster.
- If your upstream, showing a valid point then look the "nginx-ingress.conf"
- If not, address the service endpoint issue first.